# Reset to initial data in vuejs, but only for some of the values

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

The code below for a vuejs component successfully sets the initial state of the data for playerName, time, and errors.  Extracting the initial data to a function allows me to easily reset the data back to the initial state.

Great...But... I only want time and error to get reset to the initial state and I want playerName to continue to persist.

Is there a recommended way to accomplish this?  I can only seem to find all or nothing approaches or a clunky approach to reset manually that will require me to remember if I change in the future.

Appreciate you looking and any assistance.

```
function initialState (){
  return {
    playerName: '', 
    time: 0, 
    errors: 0
  }
}

//In my component:
data: function (){
    return initialState();
} 


//Call this method when I want to start over
methods:{
    reset: function (){
        Object.assign(this.$data, initialState());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the initial state and re-merge your keepers with it before re-assigning like so with a super shorthand inline merge:

```js
export default {

  data: () => ({
    playerName: '', 
    time: 0, 
    errors: 0
  })

  methods: {

    reset () {

      const playerName = ...this.playerName; // Use Spread (...) to clone this.playerName so we don't assign a reactive copy that becomes blank again.

      return Object.assign(this.$data, { ...this.$options.data(), playerName })

    }

  }

}
```

The inline merge `{ ...this.$options.data(), playerName }` is trait of ES6, the `playerName` injection is the same as writing:

```js
{ ...this.$options.data(), playerName: ...this.playerName }
```

What is `this.$options.data()` doing:

```js
{ ...{ playerName: '', time: 0, errors: 0 }, playerName: ...this.playerName },
```

The three dots is called a [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), basically it is merging the `data` object into our new `{}` empty object then we are overwriting attributes after the injection.

This overall is the equivalent of writing:

```js
Object.assign(this.$data, () => {

  const data = { playerName: '', time: 0, errors: 0 }

  data.playerName = ...this.playerName

  return data

}())
```

Comment: I have been playing around with variations of this and have learned a bunch; Thanks!.  One question - With the inline merge in ES6, can we remove Object.Assign from this all together?  i.e. this.$data = { ...this.$options.data(), playerName }?  Thanks again.

Comment: I remember having a problem not using `Object.assign` so i always use it; but I can't remember why assigning straight to this.$data was bad, I think it broke reactivity or nested reactivity or something.